# How to fix apple80211GetInfoCopy() memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-leaks, network-programming

When I call apple80211GetInfoCopy() repeatedly, to track RSSI, the memory leaks.

```
CFDictionaryRef info = NULL;
apple80211GetInfoCopy( airportHandle, &info );         // read WIFI info including RSSI from iOS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
CFDictionaryRef info = NULL;
apple80211GetInfoCopy( airportHandle, &info ); // read WIFI info including RSSI from iOS
[info release];
```

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the function `apple80211GetInfoCopy()` includes the word "copy", you own the object it returns, and you are responsible for releasing it when it's no longer needed. You can do so by calling `CFRelease(info)`.

(Review the Apple [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) if this comes as a surprise.)